# Timer stop watch in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angular.js, timer

I wrote a script for a timer. Is there any way to improve the code, with fewer number of lines?

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/yukoni/4/edit)

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('main', function($scope, $interval) {

    $scope.timer = 0;
    var clickme = true,
        startfun;
    $scope.status = "Start";
    var foo = function() {
        $scope.timer += 1;
    };
    $scope.start = function() {
        if (clickme === true) {
            $scope.status = "Stop";
            clickme = false;
            startfun = $interval(foo, 1000);

        } else if (clickme === false) {
            clickme = true;
            $interval.cancel(startfun);
        }

    };
  $scope.reset=function(){

    $interval.cancel(startfun);
    $scope.timer = 0;
    $scope.status = "Start";
    clickme = true;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from the issue of `setInterval`s resolution/accuracy there's a lot of room for improvement in your angular.

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

"app" isn't a good name for your module "fruitjs.timer" would be better as it is more descriptive and has a much lower chance of naming clashes.

---

```
app.controller('main', function($scope, $interval) {
```

Again "main" isn't a great name for your controller "timerController" would be more explicit.

---

You should also utilise angular's support for safe minification:

```
app.controller('main', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {
    // code
}]);
```

Notice that the second parameter is now an array declaring the names of the services/modules you require and finally your controller function (this is the recommended way).

---

More bad naming `clickme`, `foo`, `startfun` - none of these names mean anything.

---

`$scope.status` isn't the status at all - it's the potential action.

---

You don't need the `clickme` variable (which should at least be camel cased to `clickMe`). You have 2 potential actions `"Start"` and `"Stop"` - you don't need the additional boolean to track what state you're currently in.

---

Use either 2 or 4 spaces for your indentation - don't mix and match.

---

You don't change the label after you stop the timer.

---

**Code with above changes**

```
var app = angular.module('fruitjs.timer', []);
app.controller('timerController', [ '$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {
    var interval, incrementTimer, actions;
    actions = { start: "Start", stop: "Stop" };

    $scope.timer = 0;
    $scope.action = actions.start;

    incrementTimer = function() {
        $scope.timer += 1;
    };

    $scope.toggle = function() {
        if ($scope.action === actions.start) {
            $scope.action = actions.stop;
            interval = $interval(incrementTimer, 1000);

        } else if ($scope.action === actions.stop) {
            $scope.action = actions.start;
            $interval.cancel(interval);
        }
    };

    $scope.reset = function () {
        $interval.cancel(interval);
        $scope.timer = 0;
        $scope.action = actions.start;
    };
}]);
```

---

All you need to do now is solve the problem of keeping time accurately :)

Comment: I like this review. As this is "The Angular Way", I would encapsulate the State/Timer functionality in a Service and also have the incrementTimer() function calculate the number of seconds elapsed since last switching to "Running". Finally, the $scope.status and $scope.timer properties should be made into functions that point to this service and let the digest loop do its thing.

Comment: @malix several good points there - you could turn it into an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

[`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) is a wrapper for [`window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), and `window.setInterval()` does not provide an accurate tick.  As stated in the Mozilla documentation for that and the related [`window.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Notes),

- The timeout can fire later when the page (or the OS/browser itself) is busy with other tasks.
- Timeouts are clamped to firing no more than once a second in inactive tabs.  Indeed, on Safari in OS X, I see that your timer runs at about half speed if I let it run in a background tab.  See also [this complaint](//stackoverflow.com/q/16579042/1157100).
- If the entire computer (or virtual machine) is suspended, it will obviously miss ticks.

Therefore, you cannot just increment a counter for your clock.  The right thing to do is to record the start time, and on each callback, report the difference between the current time and the start time as the elapsed time.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs and I will try to create a better timer in future which will work on elapsed time btw start and current time.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @RobH himself, I've turned my comment into an additionnal answer:

- As this is "The Angular Way", I would encapsulate the State/Timer functionality in a Service
- I would have the `incrementTimer()` function calculate the number of seconds elapsed since last switching to `"Running"`
- Finally, the `$scope.status` and `$scope.timer` properties should be made into functions that point to this Service and let the `$digest()` loop do its thing